# Custom form template for translatable in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, templates

I need to tweak the default form template that Translatable uses so that I can insert some custom html, but only under certain circumstances.

Currently, the template is defined in config.yml as such:

```
a2lix_translation_form:
  templating: "A2lixTranslationFormBundle::default.html.twig"
```

If I change my config to point to my custom template, it works fine:

```
a2lix_translation_form:
  templating: "AcmeBundle:Translatable:template.html.twig"
```

However, this obviously changes the template globally, whereas I just need it to change for one specific form. How can I tell Translatable to use my custom template on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using

```
{% form_theme form 'AcmeBundle:Translatable:template.html.twig' %}
```

in the top of your view template works?

From the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template